# The code fails because value of JIT_TIME is not found

Tags: shell, unix, plsql, ksh

The below function is contained in a PLSQL package which is called from a shell script. It fails because JIT_TIME is not found. I am having a hard time trying to figure out where this value comes from. It is clearly not passed as an argument, not stored in any database table, not retrieved from any other database object.

```
Function ADD_START_DATE( p_process_type char, p_profet_cntl_no char, p_error_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE) return boolean is                                                                                
        v_profet_control_no     char(10);                                                                                                                                                                        
        v_jit_time              date;                                                                                                                                                                                   
    BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            SELECT      contr_numb                                                                                                                                                                                   
            INTO        v_profet_control_no                                                                                                                                                                            
            FROM        prd_contr                                                                                                                                                                                      
            WHERE       end_date_time is null                                                                                                                                                                         
            AND         start_date_time is not null                                                                                                                                                                    
            AND         rownum=1;                                                                                                                                                                                      
            PKG_WRITE_ERROR.writeError( p_error_File , 'PRD-01601','ProFET Control No.='||v_profet_control_no);                                                                                                  
            return false;                                                                                                                                                                                        
        EXCEPTION                                                                                                                                                                                             
            when NO_DATA_FOUND then                                                                                                                                                                              
                null;                                                                                                                                                                                               
        END;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        lock table prd_contr in exclusive mode nowait;                                                                                                                                                        
        BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                 
--                                                                                                                                                                                                      
-- A new Begin-End block has been added for jit_time function. If the value                                                                                                                             
-- of jit_time is not found, in case of complete refresh, an error is logged                                                                                                                            
-- and the process exits. In case of routine, jit_time error is ignored.                                                                                                                                
--                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                
                v_jit_time:=jit_time;                                                                                                                                                                               
            EXCEPTION                                                                                                                                                                                            
                when OTHERS then                                                                                                                                                                                    
                    IF p_process_type = 'C' then                                                                                                                                                                       
                        PKG_WRITE_ERROR.writeError( p_error_File , 'PRD-01604', '');                                                                                                                                      
                        return false;                                                                                                                                                                                     
                    END IF;                                                                                                                                                                                            
            END;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            INSERT into prd_contr(start_date_time, end_date_time, idp1_xfer,                                                                                                                                     
                    proc_type, contr_numb, idp1_time)                                                                                                                                                                  
            VALUES(SYSDATE, '','', p_process_type, p_profet_cntl_no,v_jit_time);                                                                                                                                 
        EXCEPTION                                                                                                                                                                                             
            when OTHERS then                                                                                                                                                                                     
                return false;                                                                                                                                                                                       
        END;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        commit;                                                                                                                                                                                               
        return true;                                                                                                                                                                                          
    EXCEPTION                                                                                                                                                                                              
        when TIMEOUT_ON_RESOURCE then                                                                                                                                                                         
            PKG_WRITE_ERROR.writeError( p_error_File , 'PRD-01602', '');                                                                                                                                         
            return false;                                                                                                                                                                                        
        when OTHERS then                                                                                                                                                                                      
            PKG_WRITE_ERROR.writeError( p_error_File, 'PRD-01699',substr(SQLERRM,1,100));                                                                                                                        
            return false;                                                                                                                                                                                        
    END ADD_START_DATE;
```

Comment: Update :- JIT_TIME is a database link with an upstream

Comment: JIT_TIME connects to an upstream system which accepts vehicle orders .

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the variable date is defined with v_jit_time type, but never used.In the other hand, there is a variable, jit_time, that is never defined.
I thing they could become one :

```
Function ADD_START_DATE( p_process_type char, p_profet_cntl_no char, p_error_file UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE) return boolean is                                                                                
        v_profet_control_no     char(10);                                                                                                                                                                        
        v_jit_time              jit_time;                                                                                                                                                                                   
    BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            SELECT      contr_numb                                                                                                                                                                                   
            INTO        v_profet_control_no                                                                                                                                                                            
            FROM        prd_contr                                                                                                                                                                                      
            WHERE       end_date_time is null                                                                                                                                                                         
            AND         start_date_time is not null                                                                                                                                                                    
            AND         rownum=1;                                                                                                                                                                                      
            PKG_WRITE_ERROR.writeError( p_error_File , 'PRD-01601','ProFET Control No.='||v_profet_control_no);                                                                                                  
            return false;                                                                                                                                                                                        
        EXCEPTION                                                                                                                                                                                             
            when NO_DATA_FOUND then                                                                                                                                                                              
                null;                                                                                                                                                                                               
        END;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        lock table prd_contr in exclusive mode nowait;                                                                                                                                                        
        BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                 
--                                                                                                                                                                                                      
-- A new Begin-End block has been added for jit_time function. If the value                                                                                                                             
-- of jit_time is not found, in case of complete refresh, an error is logged                                                                                                                            
-- and the process exits. In case of routine, jit_time error is ignored.                                                                                                                                
--                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                                                
                v_jit_time:=jit_time;                                                                                                                                                                               
            EXCEPTION                                                                                                                                                                                            
                when OTHERS then                                                                                                                                                                                    
                    IF p_process_type = 'C' then                                                                                                                                                                       
                        PKG_WRITE_ERROR.writeError( p_error_File , 'PRD-01604', '');                                                                                                                                      
                        return false;                                                                                                                                                                                     
                    END IF;                                                                                                                                                                                            
            END;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            INSERT into prd_contr(start_date_time, end_date_time, idp1_xfer,                                                                                                                                     
                    proc_type, contr_numb, idp1_time)                                                                                                                                                                  
            VALUES(SYSDATE, '','', p_process_type, p_profet_cntl_no,v_jit_time);                                                                                                                                 
        EXCEPTION                                                                                                                                                                                             
            when OTHERS then                                                                                                                                                                                     
                return false;                                                                                                                                                                                       
        END;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        commit;                                                                                                                                                                                               
        return true;                                                                                                                                                                                          
    EXCEPTION                                                                                                                                                                                              
        when TIMEOUT_ON_RESOURCE then                                                                                                                                                                         
            PKG_WRITE_ERROR.writeError( p_error_File , 'PRD-01602', '');                                                                                                                                         
            return false;                                                                                                                                                                                        
        when OTHERS then                                                                                                                                                                                      
            PKG_WRITE_ERROR.writeError( p_error_File, 'PRD-01699',substr(SQLERRM,1,100));                                                                                                                        
            return false;                                                                                                                                                                                        
    END ADD_START_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand **JIT_TIME** is a **function**. 
So you should search in function definitions - not in arguments, variables or tables.

Also the programmer clearly anticipates in some cases this function not to be found as seen in the comments

```
-- If the value                                                                                                                             
-- of jit_time is not found, in case of complete refresh, an error is logged                                                                                                                            
-- and the process exits. In case of routine, jit_time error is ignored.
```

Comment: Hi, just worked with the DBA team and found out that it's a database link.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. JIT_TIME is of type date because v_jit_time              is date ... so it could be using db link ... but I don't think it is a db link itself.